# lookup and insert corresponding column values in oracle

Tags: oracle, lookup

I have two tables, ACTIVITY and EVENT. ACTIVITY has a list of all possible codes (as INT) in one column and their description in two other columns (REASON and CATEGORY). I'd like users to only enter CODE into EVENT table in the app front end but then perform a lookup to insert matching description columns into the same (EVENT) table.

```
CREATE TABLE EX.ACTIVITY
(
  CODE        INTEGER                           NOT NULL,
  REASON      VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)                 NOT NULL,
  CATEGORY    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)                 NOT NULL,

)

CREATE TABLE EX.EVENTS
(
  ID          INTEGER                           NOT NULL,
  CODE        INTEGER                           NOT NULL,
  REASON      VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)                 NOT NULL,
  CATEGORY    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)                 NOT NULL,

)
```

Thanks.(I'm sort of a newbie btw so forgive me if this is elementary)

Answer (score 0):

You have an ACTIVITY table that stores the attributes of ACTIVITY. Why store those attributes in another table (EVENTS)? That is a violation of what is referred to as [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (second and third normal form). If you store the attributes of ACTIVITY in the EVENTS table, you've created a host of problems for yourself, such as redundant data (the reason and category are repeated in the events table needlessly). Just store the activity code in the events table! That way if you have to change the category for an activity later, you only need change the ACTIVITY table record corresponding to that code.

To display the values, use a JOIN in a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT e.id, e.code, a.reason, a.category
  FROM events e JOIN activity a ON e.code = a.code
 WHERE ...
```

A JOIN does exactly what it sounds like: it joins the records of the two tables where the condition(s) in the ON clause are satisfied. So, in this example, you'd get one row back for every pair of records in the event and activity tables that have matching code values. You are likely to have many events that have the same code; this is not a problem - each event row with that code will get the same values from the activity table for that code. This maintains the data integrity while allowing you to display the values from both tables in one select statement.

Comment: Thanks a bunch...That will do it for me. You did me good right there.